# Powerpoint VBA: How to specify the direction of a Float In Entrance Effect

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to add a float in entrance effect to an picture using VBA in Microsoft Office PowerPoint.

I would like the float in animation to go in the **downwards** direction

Here is my code:

```
Sub add_pic_float_in()


' Insert the Picture
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

myDocument.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\Users\forson\Pictures\Picture.svg", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=a * 10, Top:=-1000, Width:=359.055, Height:=1284.803

' Crop the Image
    With myDocument.Shapes(1)
        .Name = "Picture 1"
        .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 140
        .PictureFormat.CropRight = 130
        .PictureFormat.CropTop = 650
    End With

' Create shape
Dim picture As Shape

Set picture = myDocument.Shapes(1)

' Create Effect
Dim floatin As Effect

' Set Effect to Picture

Set floatin = myDocument.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=picture, effectId:=msoAnimEffectFloat)
        floatin.Timing.Duration = 1
        floatin.EffectParameters.Direction = msoAnimDirectionDown
        floatin.Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious

End Sub
```

However, I run into this error:

"Run-time error": '-2147188160 (80048240)': EffectParameters (unknown member): invalid request."

And when I remove the line "floatin.EffectParameters.Direction = msoAnimDirectionDown", it produces an object with an animation, but it is not a "float in" animation.

I have tried looking [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/effect-effecttype-property-powerpoint) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/msoanimeffect-enumeration-powerpoint) but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: Not the error you're getting, but `myDocument` should be a declared local variable. Is `Option Explicit` specified at the top of the module? Doing that will force you to declare all variables, and thereby prevent VBA from happily compiling typos. That said, `ActivePresentation.Slides(1)` should be `myDocument`; you're dereferencing the same object twice, for no reason. `floatin` local variable could be replaced by a `With` block. But anyway these are just minor improvements, not familiar with the PowerPoint object model. Good luck!

Comment: That... was not my point. You're dereferencing the `ActivePresentation.Slides(1)` object in 3 places - that variable *was* useful. My suggestion was to *use* it, not to *remove* it!

Comment: @Mat'sMug Good point, I have changed it to remove the myDocument variable, as it was not used that much. How do I use the 'With' block to replace the 'floatin' local variable? Sorry for my lack of understanding, I have followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/effect-object-powerpoint) tutorial to add an effect.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Oh, okay, whoops sorry okay, I will change it.

Comment: I mean instead of `Set floatin = ...` you can do `With mySlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(...) ... End With`, and then inside that block you can do `.Timing.Duration = 1`, `.Timing.TriggerType = ...`, and `.EffectParameters.Direction = ...`; `floatin` doesn't need to be there, the `With` block can hold that reference for you.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thank you for your help! Hopefully I can find out what is going wrong with adding the animation effect. I have also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548158/adding-powerpoint-animations-via-vbscript-always-results-in-custom-animation), but it does not seem to solve my problem.

Comment: It looks like `effectID msoAnimEffectFloat` doesn't have a direction parameter. Can you change the direction manually (i.e. going through the dialog in PowerPoint)?

Comment: If you change `effectID` to `msoAnimEffectFly` your code runs, so it does appear that there is no `Direction` property for the float effect.

Comment: @davidmneedham thank you, having a fly in animation works. I can edit the float in animation manually, going through the user interface, but, I am making the script so I do not have to keep repeating this process with every picture. It seems odd that the fly in animation has the `Direction` property but the float in does not. Hopefully this is useful for anyone else using VBA scripts to make animations in PowerPoint. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `effectId:=msoAnimEffectFloat` to `effectId:=msoAnimEffectDescend` creates a float down animation.

No need to specify the `.EffectParameters.Direction`

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered VBA will recognize `effectId:=msoAnimEffectAscend` to make create the classic 'float in' animation :D